# Saved model is None

Tags: django, view

So i have a model that i'm trying to save using a form which submits successfully, but in the Admin the object value None. I know the problem is in the views but i can't figure it out. Here's my code:

Views.py

```
def profilecreate(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ProfileForm()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            caption= form.cleaned_data['caption']
            photo = form.cleaned_data['photo'] 
            profile = Profile.objects.create(description=description, caption=caption, photo=photo)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile-id', kwargs={'profile_id': profile.id}))

        return render(request, 'profile_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Someone please assist

## Second view attempt

```
def profilecreate(request):
  # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.cleaned_data['photo']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            caption = form.cleaned_data['caption']
            form.save(commit=True)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'profile_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: If the indentation is correct, the view's `GET` will never render anything. But then you would get an error, unless you never make a `GET` request to this view.

Comment: Well i changed GET to POST but form is not saving the object to DB just saying 0 profiles

Comment: Well, if you just replaced `if request.method == 'GET':` with `if request.method == 'POST':`, now the `else:` will never run on a `POST` request, as it should. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view) shows a sort of canonical way to do it.

Comment: Okay thanks let me check the code

Comment: Just edited again but still getting None

Comment: Edit the question and add your current view code.

Comment: Added the question

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `photo`, `description` and `caption`, since you are just assigning them. If they are fields in the `ModelForm` you don't have to do anything with them, `form.save` will save them. If you are trying to upload a file, there are some missing bits. See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

Comment: @Denyce Does the `Profile` model have a `OneToOne` relation with the `User` model? In that case you also need to supply the `user` instance to create the `Profile` object.

Comment: Actually i used ForeignKey( 'auth.User')